# Programmatically clear Microsoft IME input history

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, registry

For Japanese Microsoft IME will store input history to recommend when the user starts typing in Japanese.

Like so:

[image]

I need to programmatically clear the history.　The user can clear the history manually from the IME properties here

[image]

How can I do it programmatically?  Preferably with c# but a bat file or Registry edit would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, a little under 1 year later I finally have figured out how to do it.

```
File.Delete(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Microsoft", "InputMethod", "Shared", "JpnIHDS.dat")); }
```

The file will automatically recreate itself after being deleted but the users history will be gone.